# How to fix redirection loop in .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a contact_us.php file that I want to view the content of using a SEO friendly URL via a ReWrite rule.
I simply want if someone hit the url `http://domainname.com/contact_us.php` it should go on `http://domainname.com/contact-us`

This is what I used:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ /contact_us.php
redirect 301 /contact_us.php http://www.domainname.com/contact-us
```

when I hit the url `http://domainname.com/contact-us` it shows `webpage has a redirect loop`

Where I am doing mistake. Any suggestion would appreciated.

Comment: Remove line `RewriteRule ^contact-us$ /contact_us.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+contact_us\.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /contact-us [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$ /contact_us.php [L,NC]
```

Not a good idea to mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` (`redirect` directive).

Comment: This is fully tested and working rule. Make sure these 2 rules are at top and are in DocumentRoot .htaccess

Comment: Actually the site is too old. And it not possible to change all the url manually. That's why I need both options.

Comment: What do you mean by both options here?

Comment: Just keep exactly same code as shown here and test in a new browser.

Comment: In my website all the url mapped with contact_us.php and it is not possible to change all. So if Some1 hit http://domain.com/contact_us.php it should convert in http://domain.com/contact-us.(working with your code). But it show 404 error now.

Comment: And I have almost 1000 lines of htacces file. I put your code as it is on the top.

Comment: Now when I run http://www.domain.com/contact_us.php, it doesn't redirect to http://www.domain.com/contact-us.

Comment: But your wrote in previous comment that it does redirect to `domain.com/contact-us`

Comment: Srry for the mistake. it did with Rikesh's code.When I testes with this code, no effects.

Comment: I am stuck with this since morning. And now almost give up.

Comment: See I cannot investigate invisible problems other than assuring you these 2 rules are 100% correct and have been tested. Just rename your existing .htaccess and create a new one with this code as shown and test in a new browser.

Comment: Just realized you had hyphen and underscore both in `contact_us`. Made the change in the rule, try it now.

Comment: this is what I wanted to say. Not it is working fine. You are a life saver bro. I hope it doesn't affect my other rules.

Comment: No it won't affect other rules.

Comment: One more thing. How could I make this in generalized manner. Like I want to change urls in this pattern and some urls have parameters too.

Comment: `contact_us.php` and `/contact-us` don't match so cannot be generalized. I suggest opening a new question with this much broader requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You recursively redirecting your page just update your .htaccess with below one,

*Redirection*,

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
REDIRECT 301 /contact_us.php http://www.domainname.com/contact-us
```

*Rewrite*,

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ /contact_us.php
```

Comment: In this case no file is mapping with http://www.domainname.com/contact-us url. How could this open contact_us.php

Comment: First you need to decide you need redirection or rewriting of your url.

Comment: is it possible to work with both? I need both option.

Comment: I want to both option in same htaccess file. Is it possible?

Comment: In short you want to url `http://domainname.com/contact_us.php` to be display as `http://domainname.com/contact-us` ? Right ?

Comment: Yes. And I have many url patterns to change is this format in which  Some urls have parameters too.